# componentDidMount() returns an undefined value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Goal**

My goal is to call `componentDidMount()` function to return some values from another method called `getUserPlaylists()`.

**Problem**

The problem I am encountering is that the `componentDidMount()` shows me value of `undefined` and `getUserPlaylists()` shows me a result of an array.

**Actual result**

[image]

**Code**

Within Spotify.js file I have the following code:

```
const clientId = 'Cleint ID Here';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/';

let accessToken;
let userId;

const Spotify = {
    getAccessToken() {
        if (accessToken) {
            return accessToken;
        }
        const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
        const expiryInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);

        if (accessTokenMatch && expiryInMatch) {
            accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
            const expiresIn = Number(expiryInMatch[1]);
            window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 10000);
            window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
            return accessToken;
        } else {
            const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
            window.location = accessUrl;
        }
    },

    async getUserPlaylists() {
        await Spotify.getCurrentUserId().then(userId => {
            const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
            const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` };
    
            fetch(` https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, {
                headers : headers
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                if(!res.items) {
                    return [];
                } else {
                    console.log(res.items)
                    return res.items;
                }
            })
        })
    },

    getCurrentUserId() {
        if (userId) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                resolve(userId);
            })
        } else {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
                const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` };
    
                return fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", { headers: headers })
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(jsonRes => {
                        userId = jsonRes.id;
                        resolve(userId);
                    });
            })
        }
    }
}

export { Spotify };
```

**Summary**

I have 3 objects that can be called as methods within my app.js file.

Here is how I call the componentDidMount() within my app.js file:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const val = await Spotify.getUserPlaylists();
    console.log(val)
  }
```

**Expected result**

The `componentDidMount()` should return the same value as `getUserPlaylists()`

**Question**

I don't understand why componentDidMount() is returning value of `undefined`?

Comment: getUserPlaylists don't' have return statement :P

Comment: @Robert Yes as mentioned in answer below :P -  did not expect that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause you're not returning anything from `getUserPlaylists`

```
async getUserPlaylists() {
        // here return missed
        return await Spotify.getCurrentUserId().then(userId => {
            const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
            const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` };
    
            // here return too
            return fetch(` https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, {
                headers : headers
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                if(!res.items) {
                    return [];
                } else {
                    console.log(res.items)
                    return res.items.map(playlist => ({
                        playlistId: playlist.id,
                        playListName: playlist.name
                    }));
                }
            })
        })
    },
```

You can simply use the below code, which does the same

```
async getUserPlaylists() {
  // here return missed
  try {
    const userId = await Spotify.getCurrentUserId()
    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
    const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` };
    // here return too
    const result = await fetch(` https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, { headers })
    const res = await result.json()
    if(!res.items) return [];
    console.log(res.items)
    return res.items.map(playlist => ({  playlistId: playlist.id, playListName: playlist.name }));
  } catch(err) {
    console.log({ err })
  }
}
```

Comment: What about below `console.log(res.items)` ? That's what I returning right? Because that `console.log..` is that line of code that returns me the array. I am expecting to return me that value of `res.items...`

Comment: So, the problem is you are returning inside `then chain`, you should return whole promise result. To understand more read [this references](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

Comment: Right I see.. I did not put the `return` where they should be. Okay lesson learned on this one. I didn't expect this..